# Rotating Android activity with ImageView shrinks ImageView to 1px

Tags: android, layout, rotation, imageview

I have an activity where a user can choose a photo through an intent.  The expected behavior is as follows:

- The image is sized to fill the parent width (minus margins).
- This sizing should never increase the image, just scale down when needed.
- Aspect ratio should ALWAYS be accurate.
- Height should be scaled exactly as width is to maintain correct aspect ratio.
- In portrait mode the maximum height is however big it can get before scrolling appears (just fill the screen).
- This means that the width may not fully stretch to parent width if limited by the height.
- In landscape mode the maximum height is irrelevant because scrolling is allowed, width should always be parent width.

Here's the portrait XML layout I am using:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:background="@drawable/gray_background"
                 android:weightSum="1" >

      <!-- Other controls here -->

      <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_margin="5dip"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dip"                
                 android:contentDescription="@string/ImageToSend"
                 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

      <!-- Other controls here -->
   </LinearLayout>
```

Here's the Landscape XML layout I am using:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
   <!-- Other controls are here -->      
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:background="@drawable/gray_background" >

       <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:layout_margin="5dip"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dip"                
                  android:contentDescription="@string/ImageToSend"
                  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

   <!-- Other controls are here -->      
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This works perfectly fine no matter what view I am in.  The problem I am having is that when the user rotates the device, the ImageView no longer has the correct size.  If I start by selecting the image in landscape mode, rotations look fine.  If I start by selecting an image in portrait mode, then switch to landscape mode, the image now displays as 1px by 1px.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of failed expiraments, I found that calling setContentView() and redoing the layout fixed the issue.  Not sure if this is what I was supposed to do, but it has fixed it.